# c++ String is shortening double when printing

Tags: c++, string, double-precision

This string operation prints out a double in short-hand, and I can't work out why. Why is this happening, and how can I get the full output like the first line of output?

```
string myString = "The value is ";
ss.str(""); // stringstream from ealier
ss.clear();
ss << myDouble; // Double with value 0.000014577
myString.append(ss.str());
cout << myDouble << endl;
cout << myString << endl;

$ ./myapp
0.000014577
The value is 1.4577e-05
```

Comment: This happens because the precision settings of `cout` and `ss` are different.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for being so prompt with their answers, I new I was missing something obvious. Thank you all :)

Comment: If you are using stringstream only for the conversion, [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its default behaviour you should use precision to use fixed precision

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
double v = 0.000014577;
cout << fixed << v << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because this is the default formatting, you can override it with [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using std::fixed;
...
ss.setf(fixed);
ss << myDouble;
...
```